# Why wagtail doesn't recognize my templates?

Tags: django, wagtail

I've created a `doctrina app`, I've been explicit to tell the model where to look for the template:

```
template = 'doctrina/doctrina_index_page.html'
```

Why is it saying it can't find it?

[image]

**doctrina/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class DoctrinaIndexPage(Page):

    template = 'doctrina/doctrina_index_page.html'

    nivel = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Básico')

    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Publicación reciente')

    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('subtitle', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full")
    ]
```

this is the main app, where setting are, I've added explicitly the doctrina/templates in the DIRS:

[image]

Wagtail Admin:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

Sites:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a template-not-found error.  It's not finding the `Page` object.  How are you calling/invoking the page?

Comment: @DanSwain like this: `from wagtail.core.models import Page`

Comment: its raised by `wagtail.core.views.serve` I don't think it's a template not found error, post your views

Comment: @PankajSharma didn't know you need views, as I understand with Wagtail you do everything using the Page model... don't have currently a view for `doctrina`. Should I?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot of the page listing shows that you have created the Doctrina Elim page directly under the tree root. As the message above that listing says, pages created here will not have an accessible URL unless you set up a corresponding site under Settings -> Sites.

Assuming you want this page to be part of the "Ministerios Internacionales Elim" site, and not a separate site, you should move it to be a child of that homepage.

Comment: This is something that confuses me: I need just 1 site: www.ministerioselim.com, `doctrina elim` should be a subdirectory, that will contain other subdirectories.

Comment: I've updated my question with my sites in wagtail. Hope you can have another look at it, ty.